# Solve equation $xy^2+3y^2-x^2\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve equation $xy^2+3y^2-x^2\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

$$xy^2+3y^2=\frac{dy}{dx}x^2$$
$$dx(xy^2+3y^2)-x^2 dy=0$$
$$dx\frac{x+3}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}dy=0$$
$$\int \frac{x+3}{x^2}dx=\frac{1}{y^2}dy$$
$$\int \frac{x+3}{x^2}dx= (-x^{-1})(x+3)-\int\frac{1}{x^2}dx=-\frac{1}{x}(x+3)+\frac{1}{x}$$
$$=-1-\frac{3}{x}+\frac{1}{x}$$
$$=-1-\frac{2}{x}$$
$$\int \frac{1}{y^2}dy=-y^{-1}$$

Then from
$$\int \frac{x+3}{x^2}dx=\frac{1}{y^2}dy$$
$$-1-\frac{2}{x}=-y^{-1}$$
$$1+\frac{2}{x}=y^{-1}$$
$$\frac{1}{1+2/x}=y$$

Comment: I don't see any ODE here, but a quadratic equation in $y$.

Comment: The title suggests that we just have a quadratic equation to solve, in $x$ or in $y$.

Comment: Problem was copied wrong.  Check it.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks, fixed.

Comment: You can check whether your solution (or the answer given) is correct by plugging it in, to see if it satisfies the original equation.  (Neither one does.)  Maybe it is still copied wrong?

Comment: If the equation were exact, $h'(y)$ that you got wouldn't depend on $x$.

Comment: The equation is not exact

Comment: The solution provided dosen't solve OP's differential equation. Maybe you copied it wrong ?

Comment: @Isham The solution I gave is the answer given in the text. I've redone the problem though.

Comment: @AColoredReptile But it's wrong it dosent solve the equation. Also check your integral with dx because it's not correct. You must have a log function $$\int \frac {x+3}{x^2}dx=\ln x -\frac{3}{x}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$xy^2+3y^2-x^2\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
This equation is not exact but it is separable:
$$(xy^2+3y^2)dx-x^2{dy}=0$$
$$\frac {(x+3)dx}{x^2}-\frac {dy} { y^2}=0$$
Integrate